# how can I replicate the slanted divs in this example?

Tags: styling

I am trying to create a one page website that is similar this example :
http://themeforest.net/theme_previews/6622929-glissando-creative-minimal-onepage-psd-template?index=1&url_name=glissando-creative-minimal-onepage-psd-template

I thought I could use the transform css property but It's not giving me exactly what I want. Does anyone have any insight into this? I'm really new to coding!

Thanks!

html:

```
<div class="about">
            <div class="aboutcontent">

            </div>
        </div>
```

scss:

```
.about {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  transform: skewY(-5deg);
  padding: 150px;
  .aboutcontent {
    transform: skewY(5deg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Since that is only an image and not an actual HTML page, no one can reliably tell you how they did it there … it could f.e. simply be background images that have those “angles” already “built-in” …

Comment: yes but there is a way to code this in html/css and I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: is that clearer? I want it to look like the picture. Does anyone have any helpful comments?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer! My above code was actually correct. To make my website look like the example you should put a background image on the body and then you can position the skewY divs appropriately!